# Regex: python other results as regexr

Tags: python, regex

I have this (simplified) regex:

```
((\s(python|java)\s)?((\S+\s+and\s))?(\S+\s+(love|hate)))
```

I created this in the [regexr](http://regexr.com/) environment and tested this on this sentence:

```
python and java love python love python and java java
```

Which matches:

`python and java love` `python love` python and java java

This is exactly what I wanted. So I implemented this in python:

```
import re
regex = re.compile("((\s(python|java)\s)?((\S+\s+and\s))?(\S+\s+(love|hate)))")
string = "python and java love python love python and java java"
print(str(re.findall(regex,string)))
```

However this will give:

```
[('python and java love', '', '', 'python and ', 'python and ', 'java love', 'love'), ('python love', '', '', '', '', 'python love', 'love')]
```

What causes this difference and how can this be fixed?

---

**Update 1**
Using raw strings will not work either:

```
import re
regex = re.compile(r'((\s(python|java)\s)?((\S+\s+and\s))?(\S+\s+(love|hate)))')
string = "python and java love python love python and java java"
print(str(re.findall(regex,string)))
```

This will still give:

```
[('python and java love', '', '', 'python and ', 'python and ', 'java love', 'love'), ('python love', '', '', '', '', 'python love', 'love')]
```

---

**Update 2**
I will use my other regex (other terms) because I than can exactly say what I want to match and what not:

```
"(?:\s(?:low|high)\s)?(?:\S+\s+and\s)?(\S+\s+stress|deficiency|limiting)"
```

What is should match:

```
low|high ANY_WORD stress|deficiency|limiting
ANY_WORD stress|deficiency|limiting
ANY_WORD and ANY_WORD stress|deficiency|limiting
ANY_WORD and ANY_WORD ANY_WORD stress|deficiency|limiting
(for the last one only allow two words after and if stress,deficiency or limiting is behind it
```

What is shouldn't match:

```
stress|deficiency|limiting (so don't match these if nothing is in front of them)
    low
    high
    ANY_WORD
    ANY_WORD and ANY_WORD
```

### Example lists:

match:

```
salt and water stress
photo-oxidative stress
salinity and high light stress
low-temperature stress
Cd stress
Cu deficiency
N deficiency
IMI stress
```

no match:

```
stress
deficiency
limiting
temperature and water
low
high
water and salt
```

Comment: I tried that but this will give: "<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 20), match='python and java love'>" so this doesn't  match python love @Ludisposed

Comment: I gues I'm wrong try using raw_strings

Comment: That will give the same results for both "findall" and "search" @Ludisposed

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew I saw you answer on the other question however how can I make these groups "touch"?

Comment: No idea what you mean by "touch".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex has many unnecessary capturing groups that are affecting output of `findall`.

You can convert your regex to this and make it work:

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r"(?:\s(?:low|high)\s)?(?:\S+\s+and\s)?\S+[ \t]+(?:stress|deficiency|limiting)")
>>> print re.findall(regex, string)
```

btw this works without raw string mode as well though it is recommended to use `r"..."` for your regex.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KuWWUd/2)

Comment: But why does this work and mine not? Can you please explain that

Comment: It works for my example code but not exactly for what I wanted to achieve :(. Because now it will also match: re.findall(regex,"we will and love") --> "and love" but I want it to match only if the last subgroup is matched, so it should always contain love and hate

Comment: My regex doesn't match "and love", at least not in python. @anubhava

Comment: Sorry it does hahah that was not the intention @anubhava

Comment: I updated the question with what I want. I understand that this will be a big problem (at least for me haha) to figure this out so it would be great if you can help me but if not I will just accept your answer and will remove the edit @anubhava

Comment: if I try "temperature and stress" it will only match "and stress" however it should match the whole string (I didn't check the other) @anubhava

Comment: You can check it with the example list I provided

Comment: You still don't have clarity in your question and bringing all these requirements one by one. You need to further update the question as `temperature and stress` is NOT part of the example list and no where it says a match should be full line or just partial. Also don't forget case of `salinity and high light stress` that has 2 words before `stress` not one.

Comment: I'm sorry I meant temperature and water stress, so my example list is correct. Let me clarify further; I search through articles from which I want to extract these group of words. So they shoudl match this partially in a bigger string. I really appreciate your help (I have been working on the correct regex for two days now ) @anubhava Please let me know if it is still not clear

Comment: I need to be offline now but this regex is completely matching `temperature and water stress`

Comment: No problem I really appreciate your help. I think it doesn't match:  " salinity and high light stress "

Comment: You need to check the linked demo first before writing each and every case in comments. I have written in comment as well to focus on this test case, you probably didn't skipped that part. Regex demo is matching `salinity and high light stress` but it is only a partial match because there are TWO words between `and` and `stress` however your regex allows only ONE word there. If you make input as `salinity and highlight stress` then it will match completely.

Comment: I understand! Thankyou very much